# Django admin add context to users and groups

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am in a process of customizing django's admin page and hit a brick wall at passing some variable in add, change, change_list of the admin's `user` and `group`  template.

I have passed a variable in index or any other page via:

```
#admin.py

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['Sched_today'] = mycustomlink
        return super(MyAdminSite, self).index(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

or

```
class MyModelAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    ....
```

But how can I pass variable to the `groups` and `user` templates(Authentication and Authorization), their `changelist_view`, `change_view`, or`add_view`?

Comment: what do you mean add context to the `groups` and `user`? they are already in the context via `request.user`

Comment: I mean add some variables in `auth.User` and `auth.Group`'s `change_view`, `changelist_view` or `add_view` so I can display something in their template

Answer (score 0):

In `project/__init__.py`, you can do this.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = UserAdmin.list_display + ('is_superuser',)

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        if extra_context is None:
            extra_context = {"some_var": 1337}
        return super(MyUserAdmin, self).change_view(
            request, object_id=object_id, form_url=form_url, extra_context=extra_context)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

You can also override `add_form_template`, `change_form_template`, `change_list_template` and others to point to your own custom templates.

Check out [Django source](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/auth/user) for more details on these templates.

Comment: You cannot import those from __init__.py before the apps are loaded. This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

First you unregister the models, then you reregister them with your own admin:

```py
from django.contrib import admin

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url="", extra_context=None):
        raise PermissionError("Boo")


admin.site.unregister(get_user_model())
admin.site.register(get_user_model(), UserAdmin)
```